# How to convert bak file into sql file (sql bak file to mysql supported) and the execute that file to restore automatically

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, vb.net, csv

i want to convert a bak file of sql server into .sql/.csv/.xml file for mysql database.

And then i need a script that will automatically pick the file from server drive(suppose file is in D drive in mycomputer and script will automatically pick file from D drive) and execute sql/csv file to restore into my sql database(online) .

Actually i have two system, 1- is on VB that runs on local host and generates a bakup file daily 
in the system and now i am going to create a new web application for same system that runs on VB.
i want that in my web application i write a script that will pick and backup file and ist convert into mysql supoported format(sql/csv/xml)(if necessary) and then execute that file for updating into mysql online database.

ANy kind of help will be highly appericiated.
many thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Possible by using MySql Migration Tool kit.
First install the software ,follow below steps
[image]