# Convert Bak into SQL

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a huge `.BAK` file (almost 1 GB) for my university project. I need to convert it to Excel files. I don't know if it is a MySQL or SQL Server `.BAK` file and for some reasons I cannot ask from person provide me about it.

I need a free solution that is easy to perform. I can use both Linux and Windows.

This question is not duplicate:

1. [My SQL migration tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344818/how-to-convert-bak-file-into-sql-file-sql-bak-file-to-mysql-supported-and-the) doesn't exist any more.
2. I can only afford free software from Microsoft which is [SQL Server 2014 Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx)(or maybe there are others?). When I open `.Bak` file in SQL Server Management Studio 2014, I get this error:

[image]

Apart from error above, [making any procedure take very long](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/359097/debugging-does-not-stop) and it works very very slowly that force me to close the program. (I am using a fresh windows 7 which doesn't update, that is another problem but I think it is the reason for this strange behavior)

3. When I follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225242/need-to-view-convert-bak-file-contents), for any table I select, I receive 
   (0 row(s) affected) message. I am not sure even if there is any data loaded in SQL server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot "open" a `.bak` file in SQL Server Management Studio - you need to **restore** the backup into SQL Server in order to view it (and that restore will tell you whether or not it's a valid SQL Server backup file).

Go to the **Object Explorer** in Management Studio, find the `Databases` node, right-click and choose `Restore Database`:

[image]

and then follow the wizard to restore your `.bak` file to a usable SQL Server database - assuming it *is* a valid SQL Server `.bak` file!